An endless succession of harmless checks
Similarly to my previous chess instalment, this puzzle continues to explore the underlying geometry to be found in a sequence of consecutive checks. This time however, we will ditch the limiting confines and complications of ordinary chess and replace the game with the natural infinitary variant chess$^\infty$ (to be made precise):
Can you find a chess$^\infty$ position from which the players may execute an infinite sequence of consecutive checks without capturing any pieces?
So, what is chess$^\infty$ precisely? Instead of the $8\times 8$ board, the game takes place on an infinite grid (of the form $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$). Instead of the standard starting configuration, the players may control any number of pieces, even infinitely many (but only one king) that may be arranged in any possible way at the start of play (subject to only the constraint that the kings don't touch and that Black's king is not in check). To make the puzzle less complicated (even though it does not affect the answer), we will simplify the rules a bit by banning all "special" moves; that is, no castling, promotions and double steps of pawns (so no en passant captures as well) as well as draws by repetition,  the 50 move rule or reaching a dead position. Other than that, the pieces should move as expected (in particular, there is no limit on how far a queen, rook or bishop may be able to travel in one move).
If you want a little warmup to get comfortable with the setting, you may first try to ponder the same question but with captures allowed. Have fun! :)

Maybe it is time for a small hint.
Hint 1:

 First try to show that if a solution exists at all, there also must be one that is periodic and consists only of discovered checks.

Hint 2: (Much more specific)

 To achieve the claim from the first hint: Show that there is at most one king move. Once the kings are settled, focus on the (twelve) intersection points formed by the lines of attacks on the kings. Every turn, a piece must move onto one of those lines to block an incoming check. What happens to that line if the target location is not an intersection? Show that this can only happen finitely many times.


What about the 50 move rule?

@causative Ah good point! That rule should not be in effect. I'll edit the question.


Can white 's king be checked? 2. Does black or white make the first move?


@HerbertKociemba White should move first (as usual) and may be in check from the outset.

https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/30223/infinite-sequence-of-consecutive-checks-allowing-more-pieces-say-9-queens Does this answer your question? Or are we looking for something different?

@YuzurihaInori This answers the question once you have shown that there must be a repeating position at some point. This is not obvious in this setting (and in fact false if we allow captures to happen.) But yes, this answers everything from there (although the length of the answer makes that seem a little more involved than what I had in mind)

@TimSeifert Ah fair, there might be non-periodic solutions on an infinite chessboard. I will keep working on it once I am free. Thanks!


 Draw rays pointing outward orthogonally and diagonally from both kings.


 Provided none of them overlap, these rays intersect in ten points. A sequence of consecutive checks will involve pieces moving to these intersection points, and it's clear that such a sequence will terminate (possibly in a knight check) after a small number of moves. If two rays do overlap, then the sequence of checks will end quickly after a check is made along the overlapping rays.


 This means that an infinite check chain requires a king move that gives discovered check - infinitely many, in fact. However, it is impossible for a single king move to open one line of check and block another without moving adjacent to the other king, so after this move the kings will not be aligned, and no further king moves will be possible. Thus, the chain plays out for finitely many more moves, and then a non-checking move is played. 


Not quite so straightforward, I'm afraid. If a piece moves to uncover a check, it does not have to land on an intersection (nor does it have to come from one). Also, I don't find it so clear (at all!), why you couldn't shuffle around on these intersections forever, even granting this faulty assumption .... In the end, these intersection points do play a crucial role (maybe check that count again though) and the observation about king moves is also relevant, so you do have a start here :)

I think if your reasoning were correct the following almost solution should not be possible. It is a simple 2-move loop and only not a valid solution because it relies on a fairy piece (a camel) 2q3q1/2Qc3k/8/5N2/4Q1K1/8/8/8 w - - 0 1. This suggests, that the answer probably requires a more specific argument.
